# Problema com passagem de parâmetro NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou criando a minha primeira aplicação em NodeJS e consegui estruturar a aplicação, conexão, estrutura de diretórios, rotas, enfim, tudo funcionando direitinho.

Agora, fui implementar o sistema de login e já me deparei com um erro na passagem dos parâmetros para o `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email,password,done)){});`.

Estou tentando chamar duas propriedades passadas como parâmetros, porém está dando erro:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var userService = {

    //Se eu der um console.log() aqui, aparece os valores passados.
    login: function(email,password) {

        //O problema está aqui, quando tento passar o email e o password como parâmetro.
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
            console.log(email); //Aqui não imprime mais
        });
    },
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar a descobrir como passar o parâmetro para dentro do `passport.use`?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Eu não sei te responder (pois não conheço NodeJS/Express) mas posso inferir pelo seu código que em nenhum momento você está passando `email` e `password` como argumentos. Os parâmetros da sua função anônima `email`, `password` e `done` não têm nada a ver com os parâmetros `email` e `password` da função `login`. São variáveis totalmente diferentes. Seja qual for a forma correta de passá-los, com certeza não é essa. P.S. Segundo [essa documentação](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) se seu nome de usuário não é `username` é necessário um argumento adicional pro `LocalStrategy`.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Passaporte também precisa serializar e anular a instância de usuário,você pode tentar utilizar esses comandos abaixo:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ email: email }, {}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + e }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

Você pode utilizar também:

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
```

Link das pesquisas que fiz: [link 1 Autenticacao](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) , [link2 Autenticacao](http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/) , [link3 Autenticacao](http://compositecode.com/2014/04/29/fixing-up-passport-js-passport-http-for-express-v4/)

Comment: Bom dia Pedro, o problema não está especificamente na serialização ou desserialização do objeto, mas sim na passagem de parâmetros, esses comandos constam no app.js da aplicação...

Comment: Vou tentar com o `nextTick()`agora.

Comment: Mesmo problema... :(

Comment: tenta esse comando.. eu editei..

Comment: Vou tentar agora Pedro, obrigado pela força, já posto o resultado.

Comment: postei tmb links que podem te auxiliar...